# Quickest way to generate a REST API from a set of database views

Tags: rest

I have a set of simple views in my database that I want to expose via a REST API. I'd rather not write specific code to do this. Is there a framework or toolset that could allow me to generate the REST API either at build time or run-time? Java eco-system preferred.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java world: Spring Data REST does that: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: I'm not a spring expert, but in the tutorial it creates a "person" object in java, and then uses JPA to persist and retrieve data into an in memory H2 database. What I want to avoid is creating an object model in java. I have a number of views in a MySQL database, and I just want to expose them as a set of resources on a REST service, without writing any data classes in java.

Comment: You are right, you need to write java code to use it.